# proper indexing for fast retrieval in mysql

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT A.*
FROM
  (SELECT *
   FROM
     (SELECT os.connectioninfoid,
             os.schemaname,
             con.name AS connectionname,
             wiki.wikitext,
             ot.oeschemaid,
             ot.tablename,
             ot.tabledescription,
             ot.rowcount,
             oc.*
      FROM oecolumn oc
      JOIN oetable ot ON (oc.oetableid = ot.oetableid)
      JOIN oeschema os ON os.oeschemaid = ot.oeschemaid
      JOIN connectioninfo con ON os.connectioninfoid = con.connectioninfoid
      JOIN acl_object_identity oi ON oi.object_id_identity = ot.oetableid
      JOIN acl_class CLASS ON (oi.object_id_class = class.id)
      JOIN acl_entry entry ON (entry.acl_object_identity = oi.id)
      JOIN acl_sid sid ON (entry.sid = sid.id)
      JOIN ROLES ROLE ON (sid.sid = role.authority)
      JOIN user_role usr ON (usr.roleid = role.roleid)
      LEFT OUTER JOIN wiki ON oc.oecolumnid = wiki.wikiobjectid
      AND wikiobject = 'oecolumn'
      AND wiki.wikitext LIKE '%'
      WHERE ot.type='DB'
        AND class.class = 'com.ovaledge.oasis.domain.OeTable'
        AND entry.mask = 1
        AND usr.userid = 'admin' ) hts
   WHERE tablename LIKE '%'
     AND columnname LIKE '%'
     AND columndescription LIKE '%' )A
```

I have this query what should be indexed for fast retrieval.

Comment: You have not provided enough information for us to help you. Please [read this note about asking good SQL questions](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271056/), and pay attention to the section on query performance. Then please [edit] your question.

Comment: Completly readable. I generally use the rule of thumb, if I frequently use it in a WHERE query, it's an index.

Comment: can you give two or more indexing example here for this query?